# using ViewData across posts

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a get and post method for my view, and in the get method I set the value of several ViewData objects.  But when I call the post method these ViewData objects become null.  Do I need to reset them in my post method?  Here is my code :

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["afceaststandings"] = GetStandingsForGrid("2017", "AFC East");
        ViewData["afccentralstandings"] = GetStandingsForGrid("2017", "AFC Central");
        ViewData["afcweststandings"] = GetStandingsForGrid("2017", "AFC West");

        return View("Index");
    }

[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(QBRating qbm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string Result;
            double dblResult; 

            qbm.Completion = ((qbm.Completion - 30) * 0.05);

            if (qbm.Completion < 0)
            {
                qbm.Completion = 0;
            }

            if (qbm.Completion > 2.375)
            {
                qbm.Completion = 2.375;
            }

            qbm.Gain = ((qbm.Gain - 3) * 0.25);

            if (qbm.Gain < 0)
            {
                qbm.Gain = 0;
            }

            if (qbm.Gain > 2.375)
            {
                qbm.Gain = 2.375;
            }

            qbm.Touchdown = (qbm.Touchdown * 0.2);

            if (qbm.Touchdown > 2.375)
            {
                qbm.Touchdown = 2.375;
            }

            qbm.Interception = (2.375 - (qbm.Interception * 0.25));

            if (qbm.Interception < 0)
            {
                qbm.Interception = 0;
            }

            dblResult = Math.Round((((qbm.Completion + qbm.Gain + qbm.Touchdown + qbm.Interception) / 6) * 100), 2);

            Result = "QB Rating = " + Convert.ToString(dblResult);

            TempData["QBRating"] = Result;
        }

        //invalid - redisplay form with errors
        return View(qbm);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, values will need to be re-assigned to `ViewData` in your POST controller action as `ViewData` is not persisted across requests.

You *could* use [`TempData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tempdatadictionary.aspx) to persist data for a request (it is persisted in ViewData until next accessed); The default [`ITempDataProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.itempdataprovider.aspx) ([`SessionStateTempDataProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.sessionstatetempdataprovider.aspx)) uses SessionState so, depending on what kind of Session Store you are using, the items you are putting into TempData may need to be serializable.

Comment: I feel that TempData is virtually useless in most cases.  If you set something in TempData, it shows up on the next page.  But if the user refreshes the page it's gone, so it's only a one-time shot.

Comment: @MystereMan I have to disagree - TempData is useful for when you Redirect to another action after performing some kind of operation in your POST controller action and, in this case for persisting some data only from the GET request to the POST request. If the user didn't end up making that POST request and instead navigated somewhere else via a GET, then you'd want that data in TempData to be removed.

Comment: True, I suppose PRG is a valid use for it.  But in most other cases, I don't find it very useful because of the refresh limitation.  However, my understanding is that TempData now retains that data until it is next accessed, which means if they navigate away it will stay in TempData until the session ends.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  ViewData objects only exist for the lifetime of one request.  As such, each request must re-set any variables you need.